# How important it is to up vote the comment? Also, if you remove up vote to the comment you cannot up vote again. Why?

Tags: discussion, comments

How important it is to up vote the comment?

While we can post possible answer to question so that you could earn reputations?

Also, if you remove up vote to the comment you cannot up vote again. Why?

Answer (score 3):

> How important it is to up vote the comment?

Not very.  Comments are second-class to questions and answers, which really should be the focus. Although, one with enough comment upvotes can earn [a couple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/31/commentator) of [shiny badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit) if they get enough people to upvote the comment.

> ...if you remove up vote to the comment you cannot up vote again. Why?

[According to Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134303/175248), the only real valid reason to unupvote a comment is if the upvote was a mistake.